How to show an scene from paraview with js or react ? (vtk.js.zip format)
I use this code to show with react.js a scene that I have exported from paraview :
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-vtk-4l0s8
I think my exported files are ok but there is no animation at all.
I know there is a forum for vtk.js but I didn't have any answers there.
If you succeed to do this, what is your code ? Thanks.
